Track number of kafka connection open at a given time in go microservice
I am using Kafka github.com/segmentio/kafka-go library to create a Kafka connection with the broker.
creating a client with the following configuration for subscribers and producers respectively
    kafka_go.ReaderConfig{
        Brokers:     []string{BootstrapEndpoint},
        GroupID:     GroupID,
        Topic:       Topic,
        MaxAttempts: MaxAttempts,
        MinBytes:    10e3, //10KB
        MaxBytes:    10e6, //10MB
    }

    c.Dialer = &kafka_go.Dialer{
        Timeout:       10 * time.Second,
        DualStack:     true,
        SASLMechanism: plain.Mechanism{Username: Username, Password: Password},
        TLS:           &tls.Config{},
    }

    r := kafka_go.NewReader(c)
    
        Start Subscriber
Start(){
    go func() {
        defer s.reader.Close()

        for {
            metadata := map[string]interface{}{}
            msg, err := s.reader.FetchMessage(s.ctx)

            /................................................................
            processing logic

            /................................................................

            s.reader.CommitMessages(ctx, msg)
        }}
    }

Producer:
transport := &kafka.Transport{
    TLS: &tls.Config{},
    SASL: plain.Mechanism{
        Username: a username,
        Password: Password,
    },
}

kafkaWriter := &kafka_go.Writer{
    Addr:         kafka_go.TCP(Url),
    Topic:        Topic,
    Balancer:     &kafka_go.RoundRobin{},
    Async:        false,
    BatchTimeout: time.Second,
    MaxAttempts:  5,
    Transport:    transport,
}
kafkaWriterr.WriteMessages(
    ctx, kafka_go.Message{Key: []byte(id), Value: bytesData},
)

I am observing that the number of open connections are way higher then expected. Here for producer and subscriber are expected to open only one TCP connection.
Is there a way to Log the opened and closed connections in the Golang microservice?
